# Android Drive API - Checking if a file exists always indicates not existing

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using this piece of code to check whether a file exists in Drive:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
                        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "tmp.txt"))
                        .build();
new MyAsyncTask().execute(query);

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Query, Void, MetadataBufferResult>{
    @Override
    protected MetadataBufferResult doInBackground(Query... params) {
        return Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), params[0]).await();
}

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
       if(metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().getCount()==0)
           showMessage("File does not exist");
       else
           showMessage("File exists");
    }
}
```

My logic basically is to use a Query to filter out all files with name "tmp.txt" and then check if the count of the thus returned MetaDataBuffer is not 0. However, whether or not the file exists, the count is always 0 and the message is displayed as "File does not exist". What am I missing here? I'm using a modified version of QueryFilesActivity from the android-demo-master provided by Android.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 reasons why the query returns 0 items:

1. The item does not exist.
2. The item exists, but your app doesn't have access to that item.
3. The item exists (on server), your app has access to that item but the item is not synced locally (device is offline, or cache is not up-to-date). In this particular case your could call the [requestSync](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#requestSync(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) method to ensure the local cache is updated and query again.

Comment: Such options are ruled out, considering:
1. It does exist, which is verified with Drive.
2. The app has permission to access the file, and if it doesn't, a Toast message would have been displayed saying so.
3. The file was created some months ago, so the cache was very much up-to-date. I am very sure that I'm doing something wrong, but am not sure what. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Google drive for Android supports only FILE scope access, thus on querying the user corpus the app would be returned only the files which the app has access to. It doesn't return a toast or any error because if the app doesn't have access to a file, it's not valid to expose the fact that the file even exist.

Note that if the file was created by your app itself, then it would automatically have access to it. Thus the query returning 0 items when you search for the file means either the file doesn't exist anymore or user has explicitly removed the app's access from the file.